# How to show list of certain items from JSON

Tags: python, json, file

I've been trying to show a list of comments from a JSON file.
I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "JsonExtraction.py", line 7, in 
>       for comment in len(data):
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

My code looks like this:

```py
import json

data = []
for line in open('rating_company_small.json', 'r'):
    data.append(json.loads(line))

for comment in len(data):
    print(comment['comment'])
```

Can someone explain the error?

Comment: can you share a sample data(data format) inside your rating_company_small.json?

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate over `data`, which is a list of objects, and not over `len(data)` which is a number and is not iterable!

```py
for comment in data:
    # Do stuff
```

(`len(data)` returns the length of `data`, that is the number of items in the list.)

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly iterating your list.

Option 1:

```
for index in range(0, len(data)):
    print(data[index])
```

Option 2:

```
for comment in data:
    print(comment['comment'])
```